# Modify a Python regular expression to work in grep

Tags: regex, linux, grep

The regex pattern `re.compile(r'(?:_|\.)S\d{1,}(?:\.|_)')` will find any name that has `fileasdfadfs.S[0-9]` or `fileare_S[0-9]`
How do I write the same in linux.  Trying to grep through a file to find .S and digits or _S digits

what i am working with so far is `grep  "(?:_|\.)S\d{1,}(?:\.|_)" logs.txt`

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: Umm. **Bash-native** regular expression syntax is `[[ $foo =~ $bar ]]`, and doesn't involve grep at all. When you say `grep`, are you talking metaphorically or literally? (and if literally, which specific version of grep? It's provided by your OS vendor, not part of bash itself, so behavior changes across operating systems).

Comment: looking for files name mikejohnson.S1535.txt, steve_S858.png

Comment: You're using the wrong regex syntax. By default, grep uses ["basic" regular expression syntax (BRE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Standards); `grep -E` (or `egrep`) uses "extended" regular expression syntax (ERE); you're using something closer to perl-compatible regular expression syntax (PCRE).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[grep](/questions/tagged/grep) can use [pcre](/questions/tagged/pcre) as well :

```
grep -P '(?:_|\.)S\d{1,}(?:\.|_)'
```

or more portable :

```
perl -lne 'print $& if /(?:_|\.)S\d{1,}(?:\.|_)/'
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: Only GNU grep (not, say, the default BSD grep on MacOS), and only versions of GNU grep compiled with the optional libpcre library dependency; this *can* work, but it's by no means assured.

Answer (score 2):

The regex you give is a lot more complicated than the desired pattern you describe.

```
grep -E '[._]S[[:digit:]]+[._]' logs.txt
```

`(?:...)` and `\d` are PCRE syntax -- extensions added in *perl-compatible* regular expressions. POSIX-standardized `grep` does not support PCRE extensions; regular expressions intended to work with all standard-compliant versions of `grep` need to be written to be compatible with BRE (POSIX Basic Regular Expressions) to work without extra arguments, or ERE (POSIX Extended Regular Expressions) to work with `grep -E`.

Comment: Cool sort of newish to regex.  Got python, js and a little perl down. Bash no clue.